# RollingFileAppender doesn't append to files

Tags: file, append, logback, rollingfileappender

I've looked a number of places to try to find a solution without any luck.  My configuration seems to be ok (see below) but no matter what it doesn't write to the same file after each run.  Any hints?

```
     <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>c:/logs/Log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                <maxFileSize>25MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>

        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>
```

Comment: Can you update the question to show your full config for the appender? Also, please indicate where it's actually writing.

Comment: Sorry about that -- missed the first line.
The file does actually write out initially at the location of C:/logs.  From there, it just doesnt add additional data to it.

Comment: Please indicate where it's actually writing and the versions of logback and SLF4J in use.

Comment: It's writing at "c:/logs".  Or are you asking about some other place/type of writing?  The logback version is 'logback-classic: 1.0.1.3'.  The SLF4J version is '1.7.5'.

Comment: I'm asking for the absolute path to the file it actually writes (vs the file path you had expected).

Comment: The absolute path is c:\logs\Log-2016-06-01.log

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of "it doesn't write to the same file after each run"? Do you mean it overwrites the file?

Comment: It does not overwrite the file.  I am expecting it to just append new logging at the end of the existing logging, in the same file.  Nothing at all appears to happen.  No new file being written, no appended logging being written.

Comment: To troubleshoot the rolling process, enable debug output with `<configuration debug="true">`.

Comment: Ok, I did that.  I deleted the log file to start from scratch to see what the debug output would be without a file there versus when a file exists.  There was a difference in the debug ouput.  When a file existed already, I do encounter this error a little down:  
>11:29:20,879 |-ERROR in >ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@31:20 - RuntimeException in >Action for tag [rollingPolicy] java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No >group 1 at java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
>at java.util.regex.Matcher.group  
There is more, but I am limited in what I can put here.

Comment: Sounds like a logback bug. Try updating your dependencies: logback to 1.1.7 and SLF4J to 1.7.21.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks.